# How can I check a specific mocked instance is passed using JMockit?

Tags: java, jmockit

I want to test the following code

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(args[0]));
```

If I write a test like this, it works

```
@Mocked FileReader fileReader;
@Mocked BufferedReader bufferedReader;

//...

new NonStrictExpectations() {{
  new FileReader("filename"); times = 1;
  new BufferedReader(withAny(fileReader)); times = 1;
}};
```

However, this test does not make sure that the create FileReader is passed to the ctor of BufferedReader, only that *a* FileReader gets passed.

What I actually want is for the last line to be

```
new BufferedReader(withSameInstance(fileReader)); times = 1;
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work, as JMockit complains that the ctor of BufferedReader is never called with the specified argument...

I tried using @Captured on the fileReader but that didn't work either...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ability that `@Capturing` mock fields had of getting `new`-ed instances assigned to them was removed in JMockit 1.6, in an attempt to simplify the API.

With the current API (JMockit 1.6 & 1.7) you can still achieve the desired effect, in one of two ways:

```
@Mocked FileReader fileReader;
@Mocked BufferedReader bufferedReader;
FileReader capturedReader;

@Test
public void mockIOClasses() throws Exception {
    new NonStrictExpectations() {{
        new FileReader("filename");
        result = new Delegate() {
            void captureIt(Invocation inv) {
                capturedReader = inv.getInvokedInstance();
            }
        };
        times = 1;

        new BufferedReader(with(new Delegate<Reader>() {
            void check(Reader in) { assertSame(capturedReader, in); }
        }));
        times = 1;
    }};

    new BufferedReader(new FileReader("filename"));
}

@Test
public void mockIOClasses2() throws Exception
{
    new NonStrictExpectations() {{
        new FileReader("filename");
        result = new Delegate() {
            void captureIt(Invocation inv) {
                capturedReader = inv.getInvokedInstance();
            }
        };
    }};

    new BufferedReader(new FileReader("filename"));

    new Verifications() {{
        FileReader r;
        new BufferedReader(r = withCapture());
        assertSame(capturedReader, r);
    }};
}
```

This said, however, I would recommend to avoid mocking the JRE IO classes. Both tests above are too tightly coupled to implementations details. The best approach is to just use a real file; you should be able to use a small test file (in the "test" source dir) here, perhaps creating it as a temporary file in the test itself.

Comment: where in the documentation is this expectation on constructors described?

Comment: @beluchin In the section on "delegates" in the [tutorial](http://jmockit.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/www/tutorial/BehaviorBasedTesting.html#delegates). It doesn't mention the `Invocation` parameter, though, which currently is only described in another chapter of the tutorial, and in the API documentation.

Comment: +1 for mentioning that the test it too coupled to implementation details and for recommending using a small test file.