# How to capture an instance of a mocked type created within the test?

Tags: java, jmockit

I am trying to capture an instance of a mocked type that is created within the test. I cannot get it to work.

Given the class:

```
public class Foo {}
```

The following test fails:

```
@RunWith(JMockit.class)
public class FooTest {

    @Test
    public void capturing(@Capturing Foo expected) {
        final Foo actual = new Foo();
        assertThat(actual, is(theInstance(expected)));
    }

}
```

Any idea what I could be doing wrong?

I also tried using a field instead of a test argument (see below) and it fails too:

```
@RunWith(JMockit.class)
public class FooTest {

    // The captured instance is now a field, instead of a test parameter.
    @Capturing private Foo expected;

    @Test
    public void capturing() {
        final Foo actual = new Foo();
        assertThat(actual, is(theInstance(expected)));
    }

}
```

The [documentation](http://jmockit.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/www/tutorial/BehaviorBasedTesting.html#capturing) states that it should work, but I am not able to get it work.

Thanks

JMockit v1.7

Comment: The documentation does *not* say it should work. `@Capturing` used to assign captured instances to a mock field, but it never did so for mock *parameters*.

Comment: @Rogério the example in the documentation referenced above specifically uses `@Capturing` on mock parameters. You mention in your comment that capture instances are no longer assigned to mock fields ... I think the documentation needs a little work in that area to add one more bit of awesomeness to an already awesome piece of software.

Comment: Yes, I will try and improve that part of the documentation. I guess the confusing thing is that it says that "new instances become *associated* with the corresponding mock field or mock parameter". This "association" is an important part of the `@Capturing` feature, but it does not mean that the captured instances are *assigned* to the mock field or mock parameter; they are only associated with it so that corresponding expectations can be recorded and/or verified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Inspired by an answer to another question on this site](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22869863/614800), I got it to work with:

```
@RunWith(JMockit.class)
public class FooTest {

    @Test
    public void capturing(@Mocked final Foo unused) {
        final Foo expected[] = new Foo[1];
        new Expectations() {{
            new Foo();
            result = new Delegate() {
                void captureIt(Invocation inv) {
                    expected[0] = (Foo) inv.getInvokedInstance();
                }
            };
        }};

        final Foo actual = new Foo();
        assertThat(actual, is(theInstance(expected[0])));
    }

}
```

Yuck.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is as follows:

```
@Test
public void capturing(@Mocked Foo unused)
{
    final Foo actual = new Foo();

    new Verifications() {{
        List<Foo> expected = withCapture(new Foo());
        assertThat(actual, is(theInstance(expected.get(0))));
    }};
}
```

However, the `withCapture(T)` method used above was only added in JMockit 1.8, which has not been released yet.